# webpack2: meaningful names of chunks

Tags: webpack

Webpack2. Generated additional chunks have names like "0.js" "1.js" is it possible to have something more meaningful, for example based on upper modules names included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the name and chunkhash as follows

```
 chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js'
```